# Proving that the relationship is Partial Order

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I knew that in order to prove that it is a partial order, we have to prove that it is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive, but I am having trouble with relating the theory with this question. Could someone please help?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, reflexivity is clear $(a,a)\preceq (a,a)$.

Antisymmetry: If $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)$ and $(c,d)\preceq (a,b)$, then $a\geq c$, $a+b\leq c+d$, and $c\geq a$, $c+d\leq a+b$.

But $a\leq c$ and $c\leq a$ imply that $a=c$.

Then $a+b\leq c+d$ and $c+d\leq a+b$ imply $a+b\leq a+d$ and $a+d\leq a+b$. By the shortening rule (shortening by $a$), $b\leq d$ and $d\leq b$ which implies $b=d$.

Transitivity: Let $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)$ and $(c,d)\preceq (e,f)$. Then $a\geq c$, $c\geq f$ and so by transitivity $a\geq f$. Moreover, $a+b\leq c+d$ and $c+d\leq e+f$. By transitivity $a+b\leq e+f$. Hence, $(a,b)\preceq (e,f)$.

Done

Note that $a\leq b$ if there exists an integer $z\geq 0$ such that $a+z=b$.